# How to pass argument from gradle exec task to commandline

Tags: batch-file, gradle, sh, build.gradle, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to hook up a bat and sh file (depending on the OS being run on) with the gradle exec task. But I'm unable to figure out how to send an argument to bat/sh from the exec task.

```
task testing(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '.'

    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        if ( project.hasProperty("arg1") ) {
            println arg1
            args arg1
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'run.bat'
        }else{
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'run.bat'
        }
   }else {
        if ( project.hasProperty("arg1") ) {
            args arg1
            commandLine './run.sh'
        }else{
            commandLine './run.sh'
        }
   }
}
```

If I run this task as : `gradle testing -Parg1=test`, in `println arg1`, it prints test

But how do I pass on this test as argument to the bat/sh file.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with shell files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pass the arg via the `commandLine`

**Windows**

```
commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'run.bat' ,arg1
```

**Linux / mac**

```
commandLine './run.sh' , arg1
```

Comment: this works with gradle 3.5 as well. You can follow this syntax in groovy file as well